# Create new JSON array from given JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example I have an array like this

```json
{
  "employees": [
    { "name": "Ram", "email": "ram@gmail.com", "age": 23 },
    { "name": "Shyam", "email": "shyam23@gmail.com", "age": 28 },
    { "name": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com", "age": 33 },
    { "name": "Bob", "email": "bob32@gmail.com", "age": 41 }
  ]
}
```

If I want an array like `{"sam","shyan","john","bob"}` I got it , just using map

```js
arrayname.map((item) => item.name);
```

BUT if I want an array like this from above array

```json
{
  "employees": [
    { "name": "Ram", "email": "ram@gmail.com" },
    { "name": "Shyam", "email": "shyam23@gmail.com" },
    { "name": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com" },
    { "name": "Bob", "email": "bob32@gmail.com" }
  ]
}
```

How can I do that? Thank you a lots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:

```js
array.employees.map(function(item, _i, _array){
  return item.name;
});
```

Would get you an array in the form:

```json
[
  "sam", "shyan", "john", "bob"
]
// But not {"sam", "shyan", "john", "bob"}. These are other things.
```

As the type of item you want is in the form:

```js
{ name: "Ram", email: "ram@gmail.com" }
```

You want your function to return an object for each item it receives.
There are (maybe really) thousands of ways to do so. Let's try something simple:

```js
function(item, _i, _array){
  // returning an object
  return {
    // the 'name' property takes the value from the item
    name: item.name,
    // same for the 'email'
    email: item.email
  };
}
```

Comment: Btw how can i get `{"sam", "shyan", "john", "bob"}`? I notice that when i create an array using map it alway wrap with another object, now i understand

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh An array created with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (link to the MDN, the best place for the documentation) will be an, er... an Array. And [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)s are JS objects.

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh What I said about the ```{"sam", "john", "bob"}``` thing is actually ```{ sam, john, bob }```, which is related to the [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 3):

For the general situation where you want to remove one property from all objects in an array, you can destructure that property and collect the rest with rest syntax.

```js
const employees = [    
    {"name":"Ram", "email":"ram@gmail.com", "age":23},    
    {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyam23@gmail.com", "age":28},  
    {"name":"John", "email":"john@gmail.com", "age":33},    
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "age":41}   
];

const result = employees.map(({ age, ...rest }) => rest);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to keep a number of them, then destructure those and list them in the returned object.

```js
const employees = [    
    {"name":"Ram", "email":"ram@gmail.com", "age":23},    
    {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyam23@gmail.com", "age":28},  
    {"name":"John", "email":"john@gmail.com", "age":33},    
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "age":41}   
];

const result = employees.map(({ name, email }) => ({ name, email }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: No , that was an example,  i have tons of item, then if i want to keep 2 of them, how can i do that?, but thank you btw bro

Comment: Genial solution. I c'dn't think of a powerful (yet simple) solution as yours.